# If $P(A) < P(A \cup B)$, does that mean that $A\subsetneq (A\cup B)$?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

> If $P(A) < P(A \cup B)$, does that mean that $A\subsetneq (A\cup B)$?

I thought that by monotonicity, which states that if $A \subseteq B$ then $P(A) \le P(B)$, then:

If $P(A) < P(A \cup B)$ it is because $A\subsetneq (A\cup B)$. And visualizing it with a Venn diagram the $B$ circle would completely contain the $A$ circle. Am I right?

Comment: @Chappers ?? Read again.

Answer (score 2):

Then we have that $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B-A\cap B)>P(A)$, so that $P(B-A\cap B)>0$, so that $B\neq A\cap B$ and $A\neq A\cup B$, so in particular, the inclusion is proper.

Comment: Be careful, you meant contrapositive not converse!

Comment: The tags seem to indicate that $P$ stands for a probability measure while you seem to consider that $P(A)=2^A$.

Comment: Ah yes, I did. It should be fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: "This implicitly uses the fact that the measure is a probability measure to conclude that all values are finite." Not really, actually.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need anything about probability measures here.  Clearly $A \subseteq A \cup B$ by definition of "union" and "subset".  If we had $A = A \cup B$ then we would have $P(A) = P(A \cup B)$ since it's the same set on both sides.  So as the contrapositive of that, if $P(A) \ne P(A \cup B)$ then $A \ne A \cup B$.  Putting these together, $A \subsetneq A \cup B$.